# How to run more poll process/task in parallel than number of CPU in celery Prefork

Tags: python, postgresql, celery, pyodbc, django-celery

I have django application using celery as task scheduler.
In my scenario, I have to read some data from teradata using pyodbc which range average > 100000 records and need to load that data back into my application DB and have to perform some sets of operations of the data which will take some time > 1mins to several minutes based on the records.

For this I'm using celery with PreFork autoscaling 1,10 but my CPU count is two. My aim is to run multiple task parallelly by utilizing the CPU's but with this prefork, I could not get faster completion time for the task which has same input payload.

Example say,
I have two CPU and if I have 2 as cuncurrency and if scheduled two task parallelly using the same input payload its finishes the task by 100sec (this is the expected time for that input I'm using) each parallelly.
But if I increase the concurrency or autoscale to 10 and run 5 task parallelly each task taking more time than the usual, let say taking 400sec approx. (4X seconds than the first method) to complete the task which ran in 100sec previously.

**So my objective is to run more task parallelly than my system CPU count with actual time that payload can take to complete. but celery doc says having cuncurrency <= CPU count is advisable.
Prefork is not the only my indented even if I can get this expected with other pool type that also fine**

```
The below are my celery conf:
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALlIZER = 'json'
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

celery -A "app" worker -l error --pool=prefork --autoscale=10,1

Thanks in advance for any leads on this.

Comment: While you run 2 tasks in parallel are both CPUs essentially pinned at 100%?

Comment: No, it's just utilizing 5-10% CPU while running two task parallel only RAM usage increasing at 15% where I have 4GB RAM.